# ActionListener-like event on NumericSpinner

Tags: codenameone

Is there anyway to get NumericSpinner value in realtime as selection is made on it? Like adding an ActionListener like event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest avoiding that class as it has been deprecated for a while now.

You can use `addActionListener` on the `Spinner` instance.

Comment: do you mean NumericSpinner is deprecated (Netbeans does not show the deprecation warning) ? Would you mind giving an example of adding an action listener to a Spinner instance because I can't find neither the Spinner class nor the  addActionListener method on NumericSpinner.

Comment: For some reason we didn't physically deprecate the whole thing. We'll fix that.

Comment: So I guess now you meant using `Picker` instead and adding action listener on `Picker` not `Spinner` didn't you ?

Comment: Yes, you can also use the native API's for picker in the display class. Notice that we'll probably deprecate all of that pretty soon too (really sorry about that) as we have something better planned that will finally solve this mess...

Comment: No prob for the deprecation if we get better stuff :-D! Do you know if it is planned within the next couple of days or within a month (just to know if I have to work on something now to cope with the current behaviour, or if I ought to wait).

Comment: I wish it would be fast but Steve is working on that and his plate is overflowing. I can't help much because I'm already seriously backlogged too

Comment: That's fine there are still other things to work on for me. Good luck to CN1 Team ;-)